# Using extension methods inside extended class itself

Tags: c#, logging, extension-methods

Let's say I have an interface, like this:

```
public interface ILoggable
{
    void Log(Func<string> message, Logger.Type type);
}
```

And some extension methods, like this:

```
public static class Logger
{
    public static void Log(this ILoggable loggable, Func<string> message) { loggable.Log(message, Type.Information); }
    public static void Log(this ILoggable loggable, string prefix, byte[] data, int len) { /* snip */ }
    public static void Log(this ILoggable loggable, Exception ex) { /* snip */ }
    // And so on...
}
```

Then in any `class CoreService : ServiceBase, ILoggable` or such I implement that `public void Log(Func<string> message, Logger.Type type)` to whatever I like (public modifier being kind of meh...) and use all the extension methods to do actual logging.

So far so good... or not so good? Is there something wrong with this approach? If not, then why the inconvenience:

```
catch (Exception ex) {
    this.Log(ex); // this works
    Log(ex); // this goes not
```

Comment: You can also call `Log(this, ex)` which seems altogether more readable in this situation.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Well, you'd have to call Logger.Log(this, ex)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like a reasonable approach to me in itself<sup>1</sup> - but the requirement to explicitly state `this` is just part of how the language works around extension methods. I suspect this makes aspects of the language specification cleaner, and this requirement is sufficiently rare (and the workaround sufficiently easy) that it was felt to be better to go with the current solution than to make things more complicated just to avoid five characters in a relatively rare scenario.

Member lookup for simple names (section 7.6.2 of the C# 4 spec) is complicated enough without making it worse. Don't forget that the simple name can refer to a type or a type parameter, as well as a method. There's a lot going on there already.

When I get to work I'll check if there are any annotations around section 7.6.5.2 (extension method invocation) which give "inside information" about this.

---

<sup>1</sup> On reflection, it does seem slightly odd for the entity doing the logging to *also* want to log other things - the only kind of exception I'd expect it to see would be when the logging is failing, in which case logging the exception would fail too.

Comment: CoreService is mostly getting data over network and putting them into database. It must have some means to log its activity. If some of its operations fail, it logs that. If logging fails, it might ignore it (for network logging) or shutdown itself (for file logging) or watever - that is to be implemented when implementing interface.

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev: It feels like it should *have* a logging member which knows how to do logging, rather than implementing a logging interface itself. It's an implementation detail - not something that it should be advertising as a capability that others can use, which is what interfaces are for. Separate the concerns of logging from "getting data over the network". Write a class whose *sole* job is logging, and then make an instance of that class available to CoreService.

Comment: Then that member, invokable as logger.Log(...), must be a polymorphic class to reuse all the Log(...) code and I must make a descendant for each particular case of what I want to log to and how to filter on/off (or make it fairly big and generic in the first place). Possible, of course. Previously I implemented thing like this as multiple inheritance in C++ so that a class could implement and log its activity and be pretty much self-contained, thought interfaces are as close as it gets.

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev: Not sure what you mean by "must be a polymorphic class" here - I'd potentially just couple the CoreService to logging via an interface (ILogger or whatever). There are lots of existing logging frameworks which already *have* filtering, formatting etc - why do you want to reinvent the wheel? Interfaces are really *not* the way to go here - would you expect a separate component to want to call a CoreService for logging purposes? That's what implementing an interface advertises, really - and it doesn't sound right here.

Comment: Oh, got that. The same interface, just on another class. Not using an existing framework mostly because I don't need anything as complicated as 3 megabytes of code (log4net) or such.

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev: Do you have a significant resource constraint which stops you from using a 3rd party library? Compare the "cost" of a 3MB binary, vs the cost of designing, writing and debugging your own such library. Is it *really* worth reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Reinventing? I think it would not worth it. Not any resource constraint (and 3MB for log4net is its code, the binary's much smaller), just that 15 kilobytes of ported C++ code, most of which is formatting to taste, is not a big deal.

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev: Yes, you're reinventing the wheel - you're doing work which has already been done with log4net (or similar). Why do you want to spend time doing that rather than using the existing work (no porting required)?

Comment: Mostly because I consider using an existing framework a task of similar complexity. Original code was already there from a MiniOS7 project, so either porting what is known to work as required or learning (and tuning?) what is known to work.

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev: Okay - but either way, you should be considering using "a flexible logging solution" rather than building one into a component which *isn't* meant to be about logic. My main point was a separation of concerns, which `CoreService` implementing `ILoggable` seems to violate.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for an extensive reply.