# Extension method requires "this" to call?

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the 'this' keyword required to call an extension method from within the extended class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510964/why-is-the-this-keyword-required-to-call-an-extension-method-from-within-the-e)

I have an extension method declared in an assembly under a certain namespace, it's a very common helper:

```
using System;

namespace Common {
    public static class GenericServiceProvider {
        public static T GetService<T>(this IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
             return (T)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(T));
        }
    }
}
```

Now in a different assembly and namespace, I'm trying to access this extension method from a class that implements IServiceProvider:

```
using System;
using Common;

namespace OtherNamespace {
    class Bar: IServiceProvider {
        void Foo() {
            GetService<IMyService>(); // doesn't compile
            this.GetService<IMyService>(); // compiles
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I cannot call the generic extension method directly, it doesn't even show up in IntelliSense. However, if I add "this" before the call, it works fine.

This is in Visual Studio 2010 using .NET 4.

Is this normal or am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: This is the normal way of calling extension methods on the "same class". I sure in a minute somebody give you a nicer/more complete answer :).

Comment: you **probabbly** have some ambiguos definition of another method.

Comment: There's a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3513036/1174069

Comment: And another duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10696567/using-extension-methods-inside-extended-class-itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this normal or am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

This is normal.  The extension method has to extend *something*.  The compiler won't search for extension methods unless there is something as the "expression" (to the left of the .").  This is defined in the C# language spec, 7.6.5.2:

```
7.6.5.2 Extension method invocations

In a method invocation (§7.5.5.1) of one of the forms
expr . identifier ( )
expr . identifier ( args )
expr . identifier < typeargs > ( )
expr . identifier < typeargs > ( args )
```

Basically, you always need *something* for *expr*.  In this case, `this` works, and the compiler can rewrite this as:

```
C . identifier ( expr )
```

Comment: Interesting and well-researched answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is because you can only use extension methods on objects of that type and as your class inherits IServiceProvider, you will have to use `this.` in this case.
I hope i understand your question which would make this your answer, but GetService(); is not possible as the syntax is incorrect for an extension method in any case.

Comment: Exactly, and calling it directly would yield something like this GenericServiceProvider.GetService(this); if you didn't use the "extension" part

Answer (score 0):

The extension methods are for using in instance of objects/Class. In this case, you have a static class, which works like a unique instance of a class.

So, if you create an extension method, an instance of an object will be able to use it.